# How to seeResponseContainsJson two levels deep with Codeception?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I am new to Codeception and I am trying to test my web service using the same. Right now I am trying to figure out how to dig deep and test the output that comes from different API points. For example, I am trying to create a user and check if the response contains the necessary details.

**CreateUserCept.php**

```
<?php 
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('create a new user');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . file_get_contents('tests/api/token'));
$I->sendPost('users', [
    "first_name"    => "Test",
    "last_name"     => "Test",
    "email"         => 'test@test.com',
    "password"      => "testing",
    "role"          => "1"
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

The response looks something like:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-12 09:08:31",
    "created_at": "2015-11-12 09:08:31",
    "id": 54
  },
  "errors": null,
  "message": "Resource Created Successfully"
}
```

Now I can do assertions like:

```
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['status' => 'success']);
```

And it works like a charm but when I do this:

```
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['data.first_name' => 'Test']);
```

It fails. What is the correct way to dig into these and check the JSON response is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me finally:

```
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['data' => [
    'first_name' => 'Test'
]]);
```